# My item click listener is not working in adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have vertical recyclerview and is working fine, the problem comes when I i try to make another recyclerview horizontal.My data are displayed correctly but item click lister isnt working. I have tried to check on onClick Method in my adapter surprisingly it is working but listener is null.I have spent my whole day here to look what i have done wrong without success.Here are my codes

This is Other Adapter Class

```
public class OthersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OthersAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {
    private static ArrayList<OthersModel> dataList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;
    private OthersClickListener clicklistener = null;

    public OthersAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<OthersModel> data) {
        context = ctx;
        dataList = data;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private ImageView image;
        private TextView moviename;
        private TextView category;
        private TextView likes;
        private TextView views;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            moviename = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtmoviename);
            category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtcategory);
            views = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtviews);
            likes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtlikes);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (clicklistener != null) {
                clicklistener.itemClicked(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    public void setClickListener(OthersClickListener listener) {
        this.clicklistener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_item, parent, false);
        ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view);
        return itemViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .priority(Priority.HIGH);

        Glide.with(context).load(dataList.get(position).getImageUrl())
                .apply(options)
                .into(holder.image);
        holder.moviename.setText(dataList.get(position).getMoviename());
        holder.category.setText("Category : "+ dataList.get(position).getCategories());
        holder.views.setText(dataList.get(position).getViews());
        holder.likes.setText(dataList.get(position).getRating());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }
}
```

Here is my listerner

```
    public interface OthersClickListener {
        void itemClicked(View view, int position);
    }
```

Here is my Activity

```
public class PlayMoviesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OthersClickListener,View.OnClickListener{
....
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        rView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        rcAdapter = new OthersAdapter(getApplicationContext(), (ArrayList<OthersModel>) listModals);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
......

   @Override
public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
    OthersModel dt = listModals.get(position);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dt.getMoviename() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `rcAdapter.setClickListener`?

Comment: By the way, `dataList` should not be static

Comment: @cricket_007 calling in which sense? did you see my PlayMoviesActivity? is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the activity, replace `getApplicationContext()` with `this` and you need to actually set your other listener, otherwise, yes, it's null.

```
rcAdapter = new OthersAdapter(this, listModals);
rcAdapter.setClickListener(this); // <-- Missed this
rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
```

You could also implement a different constructor

```
private final ArrayList<OthersModel> dataList;
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final Context context;
private OthersClickListener clicklistener;

public OthersAdapter(Context ctx, List<OthersModel> data) {
    this(ctx, data, null);
}

public OthersAdapter(Context ctx, List<OthersModel> data, OthersClickListener listener) {
    context = ctx;
    dataList = data;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    clicklistener = listener;
}
```

then, in the activity

```
rcAdapter = new OthersAdapter(this, listModals, this);
```

Or

```
rcAdapter = new OthersAdapter(this, listModals, new OthersClickListener() {

});
```

Comment: You saved my day, Thanks you. The problem i forgot to add 

rcAdapter.setClickListener(this)

Answer (score 0):

To save memory make your ViewHolder static, then pass the onClickListener to the constructor and set it to a private variable (like the adapter itself) and set the click listener to that.

Also pass the clickListener (`this`) in the activity to the adapter.

Also make sure your root view in the layout is `clickable` and nothing is blocking the clicks. You can double check this with having a background that acts upon clicks and also check with another view inside the layout.